# Where is pixel-scroll-precision-use-momentum described in more detail?

Tags: debugging, help, scrolling, gui-emacs, emacs-29

[Precision scrolling](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/pixel-scroll.el) in Emacs 29 introduces several variables to control the momentum effect while scrolling.

Are these terms defined anywhere in more detail, possibly by using a formula or two to explain how they are related to each other if appropriate?

Comment: It is described clearly *enough* IMO

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what's unclear about any description you found for `pixel-scroll-precision-use-momentum`, and your question is only *where to find* such a description.

1. `pixel-scroll-precision-use-momentum` is a user option, so it's described in its doc string: `C-h v`.
2. `pixel-scroll-precision-use-momentum` is used in only one place: function `pixel-scroll-start-momentum`. The source code of that function shows you how it's used.
3. To *watch* how it's used, try `M-x debug-on-entry pixel-scroll-start-momentum`. (That might be difficult to walk through, however.) Or copy the definition of that function, insert calls to `message` at various places in your copy, then evaluate your copy. Examine the `message` output in buffer `*Messages*`.

Similarly, for any of the other "several variables" you're interested in.